# Can I use Excel to solve a quadratic based on a table of x and y values? (without using a graph)

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I have the following data sets where the top bold row are my y-values and the following rows (%) are my x-values.  Each row is a different set of x-values.  I'd like to plug in 80% for x for each set of values and find the corresponding y-value.  I know it should be a parabola/quadratic.

Right now I'm graphing every single data set and using the trendline equation to solve for each new f(80%).  There's about 260 more rows and more coming in the next few days so I need something much faster like an equation I can just drag down.

I already found a similar post from 2021 but it did not work for me.  My company computer cannot add-in data solver and my attempts at what-if forecasts failed.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Update: Table image currently not loading so re-created it down below

Y: (**420,149,74,44**)...
X1:(72%,61%,41%,27%)...
X2: (83%,41%,21%,16%)...
X3: (99%,91%,77%,67%)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z60TN.png

Comment: [This may be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857252/quadratic-and-cubic-regression-in-excel)

Comment: Try as above, Otherwise without Graph and without Data Solver, try a mathematics book.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is quadratic, use the quadratic equation to solve it:

```
x = (-b + sqrt(b^2-4ac)) / 2a

and

x = (-b - sqrt(b^2-4ac)) / 2a
```

where `a` is the `x^2` coefficient, `b` is the `x` coefficient, and `c` is non-`x` value.